# SpringBoot1.5 application.properties Malformed \uxxxx encoding

Tags: java, spring-boot

I use SpringBoot1.5, when I start up the project with application.properties. 
Here is my application.properties used UTF-8

```
logging.console_enabled=true
logging.log_file_path=logs/pdcenter.log
logging.log_level=INFO
logging.max_log_file_size=50MB
logging.max_history=2
```

I have tried all the methods I searched, Here is the Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.huo.ProductCenterApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:183)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at com.baidu.aikefu.ProductCenterApplication.main(ProductCenterApplication.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try like :

logging.path=logs   
logging.file=${logging.path}/pdcenter.log
logging.level.*=INFO
logging.file.max-size=50MB
logging.file.max-history=2
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I have delete all the other config items, the logging items left is to show the log info.

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. You may want to improve it by explaining how this code answers OP's question.

Comment: @oguz , the property keys are self explanatory. would you please explain what am I expected to explain more. I have just corrected existing keys

Comment: Idk, someone flagged your answer and I just warned you to prevent it from getting downvotes.